# How to represent a comma-separated list in a NewRelic pie chart?

Tags: java, newrelic, nrql

From a Java app, I would like to send some custom parameters to our NewRelic agent (7.9.0), like this (seems that only booleans, integers and strings are accepted):

```
NewRelic.addCustomParameter("myList", "comma,separated,list,as,a,string");
```

Attribute myList is then in my NR transactions, as a string, readable.

Then, how can I represent this "list" in a dashboard pie chart with NRQL? I would like to split this comma-separated list and use each element as a facet. If I do it with facet clauses (where...) only the first match is shown in the pie chart.

In other world, with thoses two calls:

```
NewRelic.addCustomParameter("myList", "e1,e2,e3");
NewRelic.addCustomParameter("myList", "e1,e2,e4");
```

I would expect a pie chart showing:

```
e1 = 2,
e2 = 2,
e3 = 1,
e4 = 1
```

Beginner with NR, I don't know how to transform this. And as the whole thing is transaction-based, I even don't known if I can get multiple facets for a same transaction.